# UI doesn't update Shiny Dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

The UI doesn't update the page when I have an input in the sidebar menu.  In the example below when I click on "load data" it still shows a menu on the page.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("About", tabName = "a", icon = icon("info-circle")),
      menuItem("Load Data", icon = icon("gear"), tabName = "b",
               selectInput(inputId="convertToLog", label="Are X values on log2 scale?",choices=list('Yes'=1,'No'=0),selected=1))
    )),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName ="a", "a menu"),
      tabItem(tabName ="b", "b menu") 
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, you can/should not put another item in a `menuItem`, except for `subMenuItems`. You could use a `conditionalPanel` to achieve what you want though:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(id="mysidebar",
                menuItem("About", tabName = "a", icon = icon("info-circle")),
                menuItem("Load Data", icon = icon("gear"), tabName = "b"),
                conditionalPanel("input.mysidebar == 'b'",
                                 selectInput(inputId="convertToLog", label="Are X values on log2 scale?",choices=list('Yes'=1,'No'=0),selected=1)),
                menuItem('Another tab',tabName='c',icon = icon("gear"))
    )
    ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName ="a", "a menu"),
      tabItem(tabName ="b", "b menu"),
      tabItem(tabName ="c", "c menu")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Note that I gave the `sidebarMenu` an ID to use in the condition of the `conditionalPanel`, and I added a tab to show that the `conditionalPanel` does not have to be at the bottom of the menu.

I hope this helps!